# Why is Hausdorff measure Borel regular?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Definition of Hausdorff measure:
[image]

I already knew that all borel sets are measurable. So the problem is that given any subset $A$, how to find some borel set containing $A$ that has the same measure.

I have read some text, but they only say that we can replace the definition with open sets or closed sets and get the same definition (and this part I can understand), but then they claim that Hausdorff measure is borel regular as a corollary without explanation. Can any one give a detailed proof?

Thanks a lot.

Explanation of the fact we can replace the definition with open/closed subsets:[image]

Comment: Can you state "the definition" which you are looking at?

Comment: @NateEldredge I added the definition in the photo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}$First off, we can replace the $C_j$ with either open or closed sets for the reasons described in your second image.  Since you seem to be a little confused on that point, let's look at that in a little more detail.  First, suppose that we cover $A$ by a collection $C_j$.  The diameter of the closure of a set is equal to the diameter of that set i.e. $\diam \overline{C}_j = \diam C_j$ for all $j$.  But then
$$\mathcal{H}_{\delta}^{m}(A)
 = C(m) \inf \sum_{j} (\diam C_j)^m
 = C(m) \inf \sum_{j} (\diam \overline{C}_j)^m,
$$
where the infimum is taken over all $\delta$-coverings of $A$ (as above).  Since size $\delta$ approximation of $\mathcal{H}^m(A)$ doesn't depend on whether or not the closures are closed, neither does the $m$-dimensional content.[1]

On the other hand, replacing the $C_j$ by open sets is slightly more delicate.  However, it can be done:  for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we can define a collection of sets of the form
$$
C_{j,\varepsilon} := \left\{ x : d(x,C_j) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{j+1}} \right\} =: U_j, $$
where $d(x,C_j)$ denotes the distance from $x$ to $C_j$, i.e. $\inf_{y\in C_j} d(x,y)$.  Notice that if we fatten up each of the $C_j$ into an open set, then (at worst) we are increasing the diameter by twice the amount of fattening-up.  Hence $\diam U_j \le \diam C_j + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^j}$, so
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_{\delta}^{m}(A)
 &= C(m) \inf \sum_{j} (\diam C_j)^m \\
 &\le C(m) \inf \sum_{j} (\diam U_j)^m \\
 &\le C(m) \inf \sum_{j} \left[(\diam C_j)^m + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{\varepsilon}{2^j} \right)\right] \\
 &= \left[ C(m) \inf \sum_{j} (\diam C_j)^m\right] + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon).
\end{align}
I'm sweeping a *lot* of details into that big-oh, so it would be a good idea to convince yourself that it is correct, and that I am not lying to you.  The basic idea is that we can fatten up all of the sets in a cover by just a little bit in order to get an open cover.  If we don't fatten things up *too* much, we end up with the same thing in the limit.

Alternatively, we can play the same game of fattening up a $\delta$-cover by a very small $\varepsilon$, then consider the $(\delta+\varepsilon)$-cover by open sets.  Again, there are details that I am hiding, but you should be able to fill them in.

In short, we can replace the arbitrary $C_j$ in the original definition of the Hausdorff content with either *open* or *closed* $C_j$, and still get the same Hausdorff outer measure for any set.

This gets to the second part of your question:  why does this imply that $\mathcal{H}^m$ is a regular Borel measure?  It is usually a good idea to start with the definitions:

> *Definition:* An outer measure $\mu$ is *Borel* if every Borel set $A$ is $\mu$-measurable, i.e. if
>   $$ \mu(B) = \mu(A\cap B) + \mu(A\setminus B) $$
>   for any set $B$.

Showing that Hausdorff measure is Borel is nontrivial.  The usual trick is to first show that Hausdorff measure is a metric outer measure, then invoke a theorem which states that all metric outer measures are Borel measures.  I don't see how this particular property is a corollary of the fact that we can use either open or closed covers, but I'll sketch the proof here (I think that Folland's book on real analysis has a more complete proof, and one of Falconer's books almost certainly spells it out).

> *Definition:*  An outer measure $\mu^\ast$ is said to be a *metric outer measure* if
>   $$ \mu^{\ast}(A\cup B) = \mu^{\ast}(A) + \mu^{\ast}(B) $$
>   whenever $\rho(A,B) > 0$, where $\rho(A,B)$ is the minumum distance between any two points in $A$ and $B$ (basically, we are requiring that $A$ and $B$ are contained in disjoint open sets; i.e. there is a fixed distance $\delta_0$ such that there are nonintersecting balls of radius $\delta_0$ centered at any two points in $A$ and $B$, respectively).

By construction $\mathcal{H}^m$ is an outer measure for any $m$ (we really only need to check subadditivity, which is not hard).  On the other hand, if $A$ and $B$ are such that $\rho(A,B) = \delta_0$, then we can cover both $A$ and $B$ by countable collections of sets of radius $\min\{ \delta_0/3, \delta/2\}$ for any $\delta > 0$.  Taking an infimum as $\delta \to 0$, we get the desired result.

Regularity, on the other hand, is a corollary of the fact that we can replace arbitrary covers with either open or closed covers.  Recall:

> *Definition:* $\mu$ is *regular* if for every set $A$ there exists an Borel set $B$ such that $A \subseteq B$ and $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$.

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists some countable cover $\mathscr{U}_n = \{U_{n,j}\}$ of $A$ such that

1. Each set $U_{n,j} \in \mathscr{U}_n$ is open, and
2. $\sum_{j} (\diam U_{n,j})^m < \frac{1}{n}$.

Let
$$ B := \bigcap_{n} \bigcup_{j} U_{n,j}. $$
By construction $B$ is Borel (it is a countable intersection of countable unions of open sets, therefore Borel—it probably even belongs to one of those fancy $G_{\sigma\delta}$ or $F_{\delta\sigma}$ classes of sets, but I can never remember the precise definitions of the sets in the hierarchy, so I won't embarrass myself by bringing up those kinds of sets. Oh... shoot.).  Also note that $B$ has been built so that
$$ \mu(A) = \mu(B), $$
which gives the regularity result.  (Again, convince yourself that this is true.)

[1] Note that $C(m)$ is some constant that depends on $m$.  Specifically, it is $\omega_m / 2^m$.  I typically define the Hausdorff content without this constant, since it seems like a distraction to me, and can always be recovered later if need be.

Answer (score 0):

For any subset $A \subset X$, take closed sets (e.g. closed balls) $E_{i,j}$ such that for every $i$ we have the properties:

1. $A \subset \cup_{j} E_{i,j}$ and
2. $d(E_{i,j}) \leq \frac{1}{i}$
3. $\sum_j \Big(\frac{d(E_{i,j})}{2}\Big)^m \leq \mathcal{H}^{m}_{\frac{1}{i}}(A) + \frac{1}{i}$

here $d(E)$ denotes the diameter of the set $E$.

Then, take $B=\cap_i \cup_j E_{i,j}$.
$B$ is Borel because $E_{i,j}$ are closed, hence Borel. 
$A \subset B$, by property 1. Thus, $\mathcal{H}^{m}(A) \subset \mathcal{H}^{m}(B)$. 
Finally, by definition of $\mathcal{H}^m_{\delta}$ and by properties 1 and 2, and then property 3, this gives:
$\mathcal{H}^m_{\frac{1}{i}}(B) \leq \mathcal{H}^{m}_{\frac{1}{i}}(A) + \frac{1}{i}$, and letting $i \to \infty$, we get  $\mathcal{H}^{m}(B) \leq \mathcal{H}^{m}(A)$ as we wanted.